# Log Facebook chat conversations

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

How can I save the logs of a Facebook chat conversation?

For long conversations, scrolling up thousand times (and waiting older messages are loaded) is a very long process.

**Is there a good way (including scripting?) to log Facebook chat conversations easily?**

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/405183566203254) says:

> [Download your info](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/131112897028467) and get a history of the conversations you’ve had on Facebook Chat (a complete history is available directly from your messages inbox).

Some other options:

- There is a Chrome extension called [Messages Saver for Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/chatsaver/). You can choose whether to save your chat as just text, then only text messages will be saved, or as an .html file with all smileys, emoji, pictures and other files that you sent in your chat. Or even as a zip file with all the files of your chat saved locally to your computer.
- There is a Firefox extension called [FB Chat History Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/facebook-chat-history-manager/?src=search).
- If you use an Android device, there's an app called **Message Backup for Facebook**. Log in to Facebook through the app, go to the conversation and download it. It would be saved in .CSV file.
- Here is a [python script to download Facebook chats](https://github.com/RaghavSood/FBMessageScraper).
- Here is another [Python script](https://github.com/5agado/conversation-analyzer) for Facebook scraper and parser.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try these. `a complete history is available directly from your messages inbox` do you have a screenshot I don't find it?

Comment: No I don't have SS. Go to **Settings->Download a copy of your Facebook data->Start My Archive**.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but will still add my two cents.
There's an extension for the Chrome browser that can download your Facebook chats.

There are various formats - plain text, HTML file with all the media embedded, a CSV sheet, and a ZIP archive including all the media ever sent in a chat.

You can either install it from the Store or as a developer version.

Here's a link [Messages Saver for Facebook](https://chatsaver.org)